# How to get authorization code for GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest in Java?

Tags: java, token, google-plus-signin

```
        HttpTransport netTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        GoogleTokenResponse token;
        try {
            token = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                    netTransport,
                    jsonFactory,
                    CLIENT_ID,
                    CLIENT_SECRET,
                    CODE,
                    REDIRECT).execute();

            GoogleCredential cd = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token
                    .getAccessToken());

            Plus plus = Plus
                    .builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory())
                    .setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
                        .setHttpRequestInitializer(cd).build();

            Person profile = plus.people().get("me").execute();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hi all, I'm trying to get some user information from Google + in my Google App Engine app, but I'm stuck on what to put/how to get the CODE parameter for GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get de CODE from redirect URL.

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
                JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
        Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE)).setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();
String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
res.sendRedirect(url);
```

Comment: What is REDIRECT_URI?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to improve Remy Ticona's answer. 
Basic oAuth authorization flow is:

1. Request access from user. You app should redirect user to Authorization url. At that page Google ask user for access.
2. After user grant access he will be redirected to REDIRECT_URL. There you might choose option best for you:

   1. Your app has build-in web browser. Use `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto` for url. When user grants access your app should read access code from title of web page.
   2. Your app as web-server. Use url of your web-app. Access code will be a query parameter and you can handle it
   3. Your app doesn't have features described above. Use `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` as REDIRECT_URL. When user grants access he will be redirected to page with access code and request to copy and paste it to your app.

Detailed information you can find here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp?hl=RU#choosingredirecturi

Small example:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow authorizationCodeFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
                    .Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret, scopes)
                    .setCredentialDataStore(new MemoryDataStoreFactory().getDataStore("tokens"))
                    .build();
String userId = "user-id";
Credential credential = authorizationCodeFlow.loadCredential(userId);
if (credential == null) {
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorizationUrl = authorizationCodeFlow.newAuthorizationUrl();
        authorizationUrl.setRedirectUri(GoogleOAuthConstants.OOB_REDIRECT_URI);
        LOGGER.error("Please, authorize application. Visit {}", authorizationUrl);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String code = s.nextLine();
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest tokenRequest = authorizationCodeFlow.newTokenRequest(code);
        tokenRequest.setRedirectUri(GoogleOAuthConstants.OOB_REDIRECT_URI);
        GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = tokenRequest.execute();
        credential = authorizationCodeFlow.createAndStoreCredential(tokenResponse, userId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is if you want to get the code from google api

```
List<String> responsetype = Arrays.asList("code");

// Step 1: Authorize -->
String authorizationUrl = new GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl(clientId, redirectUrl, Arrays.asList(scope))
            .setResponseTypes(responsetype)
            .build();

// Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
System.out.println(authorizationUrl);
```

it will return a Url hit the url from browser and you will get a code in a response.